# How to scale imageview / bitmap and pixels versus dips

Tags: android

I have an imageview on a linearlayout.

I would like the imageview to scale the bitmap it holds, so it takes max amount of space in the linear layout, but still keeps proper image scale.

```
  public static void sharedUtilScaleImage(ImageView view)
  {
      Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
      //--
      Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();
      int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
      int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
      int widthParent = view.getWidth();      
      int heightParent = view.getHeight();      
      //--
      float density = 1;
      if (true) {
        density = MicApp.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
      }
      //--
      float xScale = ((float) widthParent * density) / bitmapWidth; 
      float yScale = ((float) heightParent * density) / bitmapHeight;
      float minScale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);  
      //-- 
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postScale(minScale, minScale);
      //--
      Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, matrix, true);
      BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);
      view.setImageDrawable(result);      
  }
```

For reference, I found some of above code here:
htttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114085/how-to-create-white-border-around-bitmap

However, I find above a bit puzzling.

- I store all my bitmaps in drawable-hdpi
- The bitmap .getHeight/.getWidth returns the actual pixels (and not density altered pixels)
- however the view .getHeight / .getWidth returns pixels that are smaller than their actual pixel usage on the phone. I need to multiply them with density to get the actual pixels.

Why the difference in values returned?

I like my bitmaps return their actual pixel size. But I read elsewhere that would require them to be placed in "res/drawable-nodpi", so that seems like an additional inconsistency?

For reference the code that places bitmap in imageview, and imageview inside linear layout looks like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(picIDs[position]);                       
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);        
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);        
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);                
//--
linearLayoutInner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
linearLayoutInner.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just using `CENTER_INSIDE` on `ImageView`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: That did not scale the image inside, only centered it. I have added that code now as well, so you can see it :)

Comment: But even if CENER_INSIDE would solve my problem (which in my tests it did not) I am still curious about my questions as I want to understand Android as much as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to set your imageview to auto adjust bounds: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean) and the scale type to FIT_CENTER

Bitmap has getScaledWidth & getScaledHeight which will give you the adjusted dimensions (pass in the display metrics from your resources)
A View's getWidth & getHeight should give the pixel values of the size, but if the parent has any padding, MATCH_PARENT / FILL_PARENT will match the parent size minus the padding (or margin).

Comment: Thanks for the link to **setAdjustViewBounds**. It could look like that might would have worked. (For reference though, the view does not give anywhere near the correct pixel size. I have to multiply them with he density to get correct size.)

Comment: Are you running your app on a tablet with screen compatibility mode on?

Comment: I am running it on Samsung Galaxy II (4.3 inch I think)

Comment: Maybe I am thinking of View.getMeasuredWidth() & Height rather than getWidth() & Height

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do it:

1. Using Rendering Script- it will give you pretty fast output if the images are huge
2. Using java code - you can do it directly through streams in the scale of 2
3. To get it pixel perfect instead of dpi - use the DisplayMetric and get the inter-conversion between pixels and dpi and then apply it to the Bitmap reference for scaling

Comment: The code I have now works. I am confused why it works. My question was: Why does the bitmap .getHeight/.getWidth return the actual pixel size (and not density altered pixels), but the view .getHeight / .getWidth returns pixels that are *much* smaller than their actual pixel usage on the phone. (i.e. I need to multiply them with density to get the actual pixels.)

Comment: Thus there are also accompanying methods of getScaledWidth and getScaledHeight  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

For your bitmaps that you want in original size just create folder 'drawable' and place them there.

Your code for scaling image seems proper, I have one warning your View is still going to be the same size as before scaling. Because of that you can have some visual side effects like blank space around image or Android will still scale image if you defined some scale type.
You can avoid this if you set your View's size based on your scaled bitmap.

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() * scaleFactor), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() * scaleFactor), true);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();               
params.width = bitmap.getWidth();
params.height = bitmap.getHeight();
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I see how this could be useful. Unfortunatelym he last call to setLayoutParams seem to be ignored. (Does not alter width/height of the imageview containing the bitmap.) For now, I set a transparentt color instead, but would be nice to have imageview resize since I then could start adding a border/background or similar